# Custom border in css for woocommerce

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating for my client a woocommerce shop.
he wanted that all the product images should have a border (or shape) as the image below:
[image: border shape]

I know that to access the product image i just have to select:

```
.woocommerce .product img {
   //code
}
```

but I don't know how to create such a border.

can you help me with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `clip-path: polygon()` CSS property. Please see the example.

From your use-case, you need to put the image in the inside div. And if you want rounded corners, then you need to add more points to make it rounded (or may be try `clip-path:circle()` property).

```css
.outside {
  position: relative;
 width: 70vmin;
 height: 70vmin;
 background: tomato;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 8%, 50% 0, 94% 7%, 100% 50%, 94% 93%, 50% 100%, 7% 94%, 0 49%);

  clip-path: polygon(5% 8%, 50% 0, 94% 7%, 100% 50%, 94% 93%, 50% 100%, 7% 94%, 0 49%);
}

.inside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: white;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 8%, 50% 0, 94% 7%, 100% 50%, 94% 93%, 50% 100%, 7% 94%, 0 49%);

  clip-path: polygon(5% 8%, 50% 0, 94% 7%, 100% 50%, 94% 93%, 50% 100%, 7% 94%, 0 49%);
}

/* Center the demo */
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, That's exactly what i was looking for. Is there any other way to make it more rounded edges? because with circle it won't work.

Comment: You need to add more points to make it look rounded. Try this https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/